# How to implement non-teams auth for teamsfx created react app?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

Is there an example of adding authentication to a teamsfx created react app for when accessed directly with the browser, no teams?  The teamfx specific mgt-element version is giving me trouble when trying to implement this.

Thanks!
Ed

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TeamsFx SDKs needs to run in Teams, you can create a Tab project with TeamsFx Toolkit and add your auth provider in the project.
To create a Tab project, you can run the following command with latest TeamsFx CLI:

```
teamsfx new --interactive false --capabilities tab-non-sso --app-name yourApp
```

To add your auth provider, this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt-msal2-provider) may help you, and you can also refer to this [wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/msal2) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, it does look like using a non-sso tab will let me do what I want.